# Prioritize file in ~/.local/bin over /usr/bin

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, bin

I'm trying to replace the `whoami` command with a script that's in `~/.local/bin/`. Is there a way to have my whoami get priority so that when I run whoami my script will run instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have in my `~/.profile` file

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

and this works!

On top of this file, it's written

```
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
```

So **if you have  `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` remove them or merge them with `~/profile`**. I don't have those files.

This is what my `$PATH` looks like (shortened . . .)

```
$ echo $PATH | sed -r 's/:/\n/g'| cat -n
     1  /home/shiplu/anaconda3/condabin
     2  /home/shiplu/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin
     3  /home/shiplu/.cargo/bin
     4  /home/shiplu/.local/bin
     5  /home/shiplu/bin
     6  /usr/local/sbin
     7  /usr/local/bin
     8  /usr/sbin
     9  /usr/bin
    10  /sbin
    11  /bin
    12  /usr/games
    13  /usr/local/games
    14  /snap/bin
```

Check the path at line 4. It's before any other system bin directories.

Comment: Alright so I have the bit about including the private bin already, I do not have a `~/.bash_profile` and I do not have a `~/.bash_login`, and it's still not working. Is there something else that's supposed to be sourcing `.profile` but isn't?

Comment: `.profile` is added to your env when you login. Iit's for login shell. You can add those lines in `~/.bashrc` as well. This is included everytime you open a new `bash` instance. So first try to reboot/(re-login) your PC. If it still doesn't work then add those lines in `.bashrc`

Comment: Thank you, adding the lines to `.bashrc` seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to put `~/.local/bin/` first in your `PATH` environment variable.  Then that directory will be checked first before any other for programs to run.

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Ok I tried your suggestion, however I have to manually source `~/.profile`, before I do, my PATH doesn't have `~/.local/bin/`, but after I do manually source it, it all works. I tried adding this to my crontab with `crontab -e` but no such luck. I put `@reboot source /home/(my username)/.profile`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @sketch54 cron jobs run in the background, and have no connection to your interactive shells. You need to find out what shell you're using (bash, zsh, etc) and which initialization file(s) it runs at startup (maybe ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login or ~/.zshrc or ~/.zshenv or...) and put that command in the appropriate file.